# Iot Raspberry Pi Xcode - FIREBASE

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, raspberry-pi

I am connecting firebase to xcode. I keep getting a THREAD 1 : SIGBART ERROR. I'm new to xcode so I don't know what to do. Please help. It gives me the error at the part where it says **class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {*

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  H2KNOW
//
//  Created by Sohil Bhatia on 9/4/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Sohil Bhatia. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Please help me fix this. I really want to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: There's really not enough information here to help. What is the actual error in the console? Do you have exception breakpoints on? Did you include the GoogleService-Info.plist file? Are you using Cocoapods for Firebase?

Comment: yes I'm using cocapods for Firebase. And i included the GoogleService-Info.plist file. No idea what exception breakpoints are.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode Try adding an exception breakpoint and you might get more information about the crash.